# How to segue array to another view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

I am trying to segue an array filled with Strings from the FactsViewController to the FavoritesViewController, but for some reason when I add some elements to the array, run the code, and transfer to the FavoritesViewController it says there are no elements in the array...

**First View Controller:**

```
import UIKit

class FactsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var factsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var nextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var previousButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var favoriteButton: UIButton!
var factNumber: Int = 0
var i = 0
var favoriteFactsList: [String] = []
var factsList: [String] = ["Fact 1", "Fact 2", "Fact 3", "Fact 4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    factsLabel?.text = factsList[factNumber]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Segue array to Favorites ViewController
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destinationViewController: FavoritesViewController = segue.destinationViewController as FavoritesViewController
    var arrayToSegue: [String] = favoriteFactsList
    destinationViewController.favoriteList = arrayToSegue
}

// Next Button
@IBAction func nextButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    factNumber++

    if(factNumber >= factsList.count - 1) {
        factNumber = factsList.count - 1
    }

    factsLabel.text = factsList[factNumber]
}

// Previous Button
@IBAction func previousButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    factNumber--

    if(factNumber <= 0) {
        factNumber = 0
    }

    factsLabel.text = factsList[factNumber]
}

// Favorite Button
@IBAction func favoriteButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    favoriteFactsList.append("\(factsList[factNumber])")
    NSLog(String(favoriteFactsList.count))
}

// Present Favorites ViewController
@IBAction func favoritesViewController(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    let favoritesViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("favoritesStoryBoard") as FavoritesViewController
    self.presentViewController(favoritesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

**Second View Controller:**

```
import UIKit

class FavoritesViewController: FactsViewController {

@IBOutlet var favoriteFactsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var favoriteNextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var favoritePreviousButton: UIButton!

var favoriteList: [String] = [String]()
var favoriteFactNumber: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    factsList = favoriteFactsList

    NSLog("\(favoriteFactsList.count)")

    if(favoriteList.count == 0) {
        favoriteFactsLabel.text = "Sorry, You Have Not Favorited Any Facts Yet"
        favoriteNextButton.hidden = true
        favoritePreviousButton.hidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func favoriteNextButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    favoriteFactNumber++

    if(favoriteFactNumber >= favoriteList.count - 1) {
        favoriteFactNumber = favoriteList.count - 1
    }

    favoriteFactsLabel.text = favoriteList[favoriteFactNumber]
}

@IBAction func favoritePreviousButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    favoriteFactNumber--

    if(favoriteFactNumber <= 0) {
        favoriteFactNumber = 0
    }

    favoriteFactsLabel.text = favoriteList[favoriteFactNumber]
}

override func favoriteButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    favoriteList.append("\(factsList[factNumber])")
}

@IBAction func returnButton(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    let factsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("factsStoryBoard") as FactsViewController
    self.presentViewController(factsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

***Why will my facts array not `segue` from the `FactsViewController` to the `FavoritesViewController`?***

Comment: The answer to your question, is because you're not doing a segue, so prepareForSegue isn't going to be called. What you're doing is a manual presentation.

Comment: How would you preform a manual presentation?

Comment: That's what you're currently doing in your returnButton function. If you want prepareForSegue to be called, you need to perform a segue, like Viral Savaj shows in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error lies in the method you're using to present `FavoritesViewController`. You are currently presenting the ViewController via `presentViewController()`, not a segue, so the method will never be called. You can make a segue from `FactsViewController` to `FavoritesViewController`, with a segue identifier. You could possibly call it `goToFavoritesView`.

```
// Present Favorites ViewController
@IBAction func favoritesViewController(UIButton: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToFavoritesView", sender: self)
}
```